# Seeding my EF database with data

Tags: entity-framework

I'm trying to populate my database using Entity Framework. I'm using the `Seed` override and using set initializer from my `DbContext`. When I create my database from scratch, it doesn't seem to add these values in!

```
public class PokemonDatabaseInitializer : CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<PkmnContext>
{
        protected override void Seed(PkmnContext context)
        {
            var pkm = new Pokemon
            {
                Id = 25,
                DisplayName = "Pikachu",
                RegionId = 1
            };

            var region = new PokemonRegion
            {
                Id = 1,
                Kanto = true,
            };

            var location = new PokemonLocation
            {
                AreaFound = "Viridian Forest",
                Id = 1
            };

            context.Pokemons.Add(pkm);
            context.PokemonRegions.Add(region);
            context.PokemonLocations.Add(location);

            context.SaveChanges();

            base.Seed(context);
    }
}

public class PkmnContext : DbContext
{
        public PkmnContext()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new PokemonDatabaseInitializer());
        }

        public DbSet<Pokemon> Pokemons { get; set; }
        public DbSet<PokemonRegion> PokemonRegions { get; set; }

        public DbSet<PokemonLocation> PokemonLocations { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to call

> update-database

from package manager console. It also possible to call it from code after any migrations were applied

Please note that it will seed data each time you call it so i would add some checks if items exists already

Comment: I have run update database but nothing seems to show populated. Am I linking my rows together in the seed method properly?

Comment: @magna_nz in seed you are doing right. And you are calling savechanges. I would check all connection strings because could be that your default project (or if you dont have default then selected project) has different connection to other database

Comment: Don't think it's a connection string issue as my database is creating, just not populating.